# Unable to update sidekiq-batch runtime dependency to recommended version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile, gemfile.lock

I am currently working on a Rails application that uses the sidekiq-batch gem. After identifying a vulnerability in the runtime dependency of sidekiq-batch related to the sidekiq, I am attempting to update the runtime dependency to a recommended version (between 6.4.1 to 7.1.2).

Gemfile

```
gem 'sidekiq-batch', '~> 0.1.6'
```

vulnerable version >=3

Gemfile.lock

```
sidekiq-batch (0.1.9)
  sidekiq (>= 3)
```

To update the runtime dependency, I tried to update the sidekiq-batch gem version to update its runtime dependency, but with the latest version of sidekiq-batch gem I am still getting the same version of its runtime dependency sidekiq.

After updating the sidekiq-batch gem

Gemfile

```
gem 'sidekiq-batch', '~> 0.1.9'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
sidekiq-batch (0.1.9)
  sidekiq (>= 3)
```

I tried to update the version manually in Gemfile.lock manually. After running bundle update sidekiq-batch it removes the manual changes from Gemfile.lock file.

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to address this situation and successfully update the runtime dependency of sidekiq-batch to a recommended version while accommodating the existing sidekiq gem version. Thank you.

Here's my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) {|repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.6'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.6.1'

gem 'puma','~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.1'

gem 'redis', '~> 4.5', '< 4.6.0'

gem 'sidekiq', '~> 5.2.8'
gem 'sidekiq-batch', '~> 0.1.6'
gem 'sidekiq-failures', '~> 1.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'pry'
end

group :test do
  gem 'fakeredis'
end
```

Comment: What command did you run to update the gem and its dependencies, `bundle update sidekiq-batch sidekiq`? Are there other gem in your `Gemfile` depending on `sidekiq`?

Comment: I replaced the version in the `Gemfile` and ran `bundle install` command. 
Yes, there is `sidekiq-failure` and `sidekiq-batch` gem depending upon `sidekiq`.

Comment: Did you try `bundle update sidekiq-batch sidekiq-failure sidekiq` then? Do any of those gems have any version constraints in the `Gemfile`?

Comment: I ran those commands but, it could not update the runtime dependency of `sidekiq-batch` gem. And there is no version constraints for the gems.
My current `sidekiq` gem version is 5.2.8, I updated it to 6.1.0 but it could not update the runtime dependency of `sidekiq-batch` gem.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your `Gemfile` entirely?

Comment: Ok, I will share.

Comment: I have added codes of `Gemfile`. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

This line in your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 5.2.8'
```

means that Bundler is only allowed to install `sidekiq` versions that are greater or equal to `5.2.8` and smaller than `5.3`.

That explains why Bundler is unable to update `sidekiq` to `6.4.1` or to any  `7.x` version.

Unless you have a reason to not allow Bundler updating a gem, I suggest removing that version constraint. A good reason could be that you, for example, know about a breaking change in a newer version and therefore cannot upgrade any further.

In your case, I suggest changing those lines to:

```
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 6.4'
gem 'sidekiq-batch'
gem 'sidekiq-failures'
```

You might even want to try removing the version constraint from `sidekiq` entirely, but that might fail because its `7.0` version introduced some breaking changes.

See the following docs:

- https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/blob/main/docs/6.0-Upgrade.md
- https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/blob/main/docs/7.0-Upgrade.md

Comment: My concern is to update the runtime dependency of `sidekiq-batch` gem.
But I am unable to update it after updating the `sidekiq` gem.